# Lyft SDK DeepLinking not pre-filled with pick-up and drop off location

Tags: ios, lyft-api

I've integrated Lyft SDK. I need to implement deepLinking with pre-filled pick-up and drop-off location. I've created Lyft developer account and client id using the number where Lyft doesn't provide it's service. I'm passing the lat long of USA for pick up and drop-off address but it's not getting pre-filled with Lyft newest version 5.93.3. It was working with previous version.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
let pickup = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.043480, longitude: -118.467621)
let destination = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.051230, longitude: -118.458780)
LyftDeepLink.requestRide(kind: .Standard, from: pickup, to: destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. It seems that it's related to the Lyft iOS app. The workaround was to show web instead

```
lyftButton.deepLinkBehavior = .web
```